# vs2017-15.3.5 Nuget 400 bad request

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

When I try to browse or check for updates, this is what I get.

ps.: It's been working fine for months and it's working fine to a co-worker running VS2017 15.1.

[image: There is a yellow bar indicating error and this shows out in the Output window]

Comment: What is the package source you are using when you got this error? Is nuget.org "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"? Do you have proxy configured on your machine? Or "http_proxy" variable configured in environment variable? Fiddler trace of the call to install one package in the package manager console by Install-package packagename.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT, this is an internal Nuget Server we have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it only worked when I copied the contents from my Debug/Release folder to the server. Publishing the project always makes me get 404 when searching for a package.